# can't save the database child data to the dataset at first run

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating password retrieving mechanism for login page with real time database from firebase.

Everything runs well but the first time I press "submit" button, my mutable dataset is not up to date yet to save the password data. When I press second time, the mutable dataset is updated with the data and hence I can log into the system. Any idea how to fix this?

[my code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWAhC.png)
[my code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWCNL.png)

```
package com.example.mytrack2

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.text.trimmedLength
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.getValue

class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // late init everything here
    lateinit var goBack: Button //go back button
    lateinit var signInUser: Button
    lateinit var verifyUsername: EditText
    lateinit var verifyPassword: EditText
    lateinit var myRef: DatabaseReference
    var dataSet = mutableSetOf<String>("admin")


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

        // assign every ID here
        goBack = findViewById(R.id.back)
        signInUser = findViewById(R.id.signInUser) // Button to submit
        verifyPassword = findViewById(R.id.verifyPassword) // user input for password
        verifyUsername = findViewById(R.id.verifyUsername) // user input for username

        // create database reference scanner
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference // reference

        var strUsername = ""
        var strPassword = ""

        // setup all button here

        val getPassword = object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for(item in snapshot.children){
                    var namename = snapshot.child("PASSWORD").value.toString()
                    dataSet.add(namename)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                //
            }
        }



        signInUser.setOnClickListener {
            val goIntent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
            strUsername = verifyUsername.text.toString().trim()
            strPassword = verifyPassword.text.toString().trim()
            myRef = myRef.child(strUsername)

            myRef.addValueEventListener(getPassword) // check user password
            myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getPassword) // check user password

            if (strUsername.trimmedLength() == 0 || strPassword.trimmedLength() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Please fill in the field!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else
            {
                if(dataSet.contains(strPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startActivity(goIntent)
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "$dataSet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Incorrect password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        // setup the goback button
        goBack.setOnClickListener{
            val goBackIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(goBackIntent)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving your event listeners outside the onClickListener

Comment: Please don't post links to images of your code. Post your code here.

Comment: @MikkeIT it doesn't work. I need to press submit twice to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code that needs the data from the database, must be inside the `onDataChange` method:

```
signInUser.setOnClickListener {
    val goIntent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    strUsername = verifyUsername.text.toString().trim()
    strPassword = verifyPassword.text.toString().trim()
    myRef = myRef.child(strUsername)

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for(item in snapshot.children){
                var namename = snapshot.child("PASSWORD").value.toString()
                dataSet.add(namename)
            }

            if (strUsername.trimmedLength() == 0 || strPassword.trimmedLength() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Please fill in the field!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else
            {
                if(dataSet.contains(strPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Login Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startActivity(goIntent)
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "$dataSet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Toast.makeText(this@SignInActivity, "Incorrect password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("Firebase", "Error loading data", error.exception) //  don't ignore errors
        }
    }) // check user password
}
```